Microwave magnetron connections reversable F, FA?

The two connections on a microwave magnetron are labeled F (filament) and FA (filament anode), both being either ends of a heated filament powered by a 3V AC supply, and the FA connection being further connected to the negative high voltage too. These markings are stamped into the metal beside the connections, implying it is important the two wires go to their specific corresponding connector but is the connection order even important? Can the connections be reversed? Seeing as the filament voltage is AC and 'superimposed' on the HV DC, it wouldn't appear to matter? And I assume the filament is 'symmetrical' for what it matters?
Could anyone explain why the specific connection F-F, FA-FA is important, or not, or can be reversed without any effect, wire to F-FA connection on magnetron, wire to FA-F connection on magnetron?
Cheers!
(oh and an extra bonus question to satisfy my curiosity, why does the microwave transformer get extra hot when running a magnetron with burned out filament? The HV circuit and the 3VAC one are open circuit so I guess the primary is running 'shorted' without the magnetic feedback of the secondaries right?)

the anode plate is probably connected directly to the FA pin

And I assume the filament is 'symmetrical' for what it matters? To assume to is to make an Ass out of U and ME. There might be a heatsinking or emmissivity asymmetry, or it might just be 'brown M&Ms' to check correct assembly.

@jsotola I have a hard time believing that. How would the tube work if there was an electrical connection between the plate and the filament?

In microwave magnetrons, the anode is grounded.

As someone who works on Turbo Chef ovens on a daily basis, I can confirm that reversing the wires does not seem to matter whatsoever. I often come across ovens that have been serviced by someone else and have had the magnetrons replaced and the wiring reversed and they still work fine. In fact, that's what made me go on Google and search for this topic. I was curious myself. I do not know why it works, but it does. When I see this, I do rewire them back to factory setting though. As a side note, the diagram you provided shows the filiment transformer going to (F) and the schematic from turbochef shows it going to (FA) and the Cap\diode going to (F)
And to answer your bonus question, I have not seen the HV transformer get hot without a load on it. We often disconnect the secondary wire if there's an issue with the magnetron and leave the primary's connected and run the oven for days without issue until parts arrive. I do, however, see the HV transformer burn up when an antenna falls off a magnetron causing an arc to the wave guide, essentially creating a welder. It will often burn a hole in the waveguide. Before the transfomer finally blows its fuse.

I am yet to disassemble a magnetron and see weither the cathode has direct or indirect heating.
On the other hand, it doesn't matter much.
If it has indirect heating, the one side (probably the FA one) will be both cathode and filament and the other side will be filament only.
In this case, the reversal of F and FA will get the catode in series with the heating voltage. This could be quite an issue in an audio or RF transmitter amplifier (the heating voltage will be superimposed over the grid/cathode voltage and the effect will be a grid-frequency hum at a level comparable to the signal). But in an oven magnetron case, these 3V will be added/subtracted from the 4000V anode and no one really cares about the grid-frequency waveform anyway.
If the cathode is directly heated (this would be the cost- and startup-time driven design decision), one of the cathode ends will be at 3V lower voltage than the other end when there is at all an anode voltage (i.e. half of the cycle, because the half-wave voltage multiplier used). This, in theory, could make the cathode wear asymmetrically. But again, in contrast with the amplifier tubes, the asymmetry here will be on the order of magnitude of 3/4000, the power lost to this process will be insignificant and if one at all cares about it, they should swap the cathode terminals once in a while.
